# After setting UITextView's text property, screen does not update accordingly

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitextview

I have view controllers A(FileListViewController) and B(TextFileViewController). A is a UITableViewController. What I am doing now is that after selecting a row in controller A, I load a text file and display that text in a UITextView in controller B.

The following is the header and implementation part(some code is abridged) of my the two controllers.

FileListViewcontroller Interface:

```
@interface FileListViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray * fileList;
    DBRestClient* restClient;
    TextFileViewController *tfvc;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * fileList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TextFileViewController *tfvc;
@end
```

FileListViewController Implementation:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DBMetadata *metaData = [fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(!metaData.isDirectory){
        if([Utils isTextFile:metaData.path]){
            if(!tfvc){
                tfvc = [[TextFileViewController alloc] init];
            }            
        [self restClient].delegate = self;
        [[self restClient] loadFile:metaData.path intoPath:filePath];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tfvc animated:YES];            
    }
}    

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedFile:(NSString*)destPath {    
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:destPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
    if(fileContent) {
        [tfvc updateText:fileContent];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error reading %@: %@", destPath, err);        
    }
}
```

And here is the interface for TextFileViewController：

```
@interface TextFileViewController : UIViewController {
    UITextView * textFileView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView * textFileView;
-(void) updateText:(NSString *) newString;
@end
```

TextFileViewController implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done)] autorelease];

    textFileView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
}

- (void) updateText:(NSString *)newString {
    NSLog(@"new string has value? %@", newString);
    [textFileView setText:[NSString stringWithString:newString]];
    NSLog(@"print upddated text of textview: %@", textFileView.text);
    [[self textFileView] setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

(void)restClient: loadedFile: will be call after the loadFile:intoPath: is completed in the disSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

In TextFileViewController's updateText method, from NSLog I see that the text property is updated correctly. But the screen does not update accordingly. I've tried setNeedsDisplay but in vain. Did I miss something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In -[TextFileViewController viewDidLoad] you're creating a UITextView, but its frame is never set, and it's not added to the view hierarchy.

Try changing this:

```
textFileView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
```

to this:

```
textFileView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
[[self view] addSubview:textFileView];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `textFileView` is created in the `viewDidLoad` method of `TextFileViewController`. This method has not yet been called by the time you call `updateText` (this happens before the `TextFileViewController` is pushed).

You can fix this by forcing the view to load before you call `[[self restClient] loadFile:metaData.path intoPath:filePath];`.